# Equation for Density

Tags: physics, equation

I am a rookie and learning myself so i dont know where to ask so i wanted to try my luck here

The Equation is p=m/V

```
while True:
Auswahl = input("Für das beenden des Skripts geben sie Ende ein.\nWas möchten sie berechnen: Dichte, Masse, Volumen: ")

if Auswahl == "Dichte":
    print("Geben sie zuerst das Volumen und dann die Masse an")
    Volumen = float(input("Volumen: "))
    Masse = float(input("Masse: "))
    Dichte = Masse/Volumen
    print(f"Die Dichte beträgt {Dichte} Einheiten")

elif Auswahl == "Masse":
    print("Geben sie zuerst die Dichte und dann das Volumen an")
    Dichte = float(input("Dichte: "))
    Volumen = float(input("Volumen: "))
    Masse = Dichte * Volumen
    print(f"Die Masse beträgt {Masse} Einheiten")

elif Auswahl == "Volumen":
    print("Geben sie zuerst die Masse und dann die Dichte an")
    Masse = float(input("Masse: "))
    Dichte = float(input("Dichte: "))
    Volumen = Masse / Dichte
    print(f"Das Volumen beträgt {Volumen} Einheiten")

elif Auswahl == "Ende":
    print(style.RED + "Danke")
    quit()
```

So far its pretty simple since its only 2 variables at a time.

But for this problem:

[for average Density](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRu48.png)

I need multiple variables that differ from task to task, so in some cases i have 5 masses and volumes, sometimes 15 masses and volumes

now to my question how can i tell python to only ask me 15 times and then define 15 variables that i can use for calculating later on

For example = 8 Masses and 8 Volumes
So python should ask me about the 8 different masses and put them into variables and the same goes for volumes

i was thinking about implementing a while loop but quickly found out that i have to define variables by hand which sucks i would like python to do it automatically

i am also open for any improvments

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might consider using lists to hold the values.

Answer (score 0):

i think i solved the problem but i am afraid its not the most efficent way;

```
gesamt = float(input("Geben Sie die Anzahl der im Körper enthaltenen Stoffe an: "))

b = 1
while b <= gesamt:
    b += 1

m_list = []
for i in range(b-1):
    m_list.append(float(input("Masse eingeben: ")))
    mtotal = 0
    for m in m_list:
        mtotal = mtotal + m
print(mtotal)

v_list = []
for j in range(b-1):
    v_list.append(float(input("Volumen eingeben: ")))
    vtotal = 0
    for v in v_list:
        vtotal = vtotal + v
print(vtotal)

durchschnittliche_Dichte = mtotal/vtotal
print(durchschnittliche_Dichte)
```

Comment: also i am not sure why i have to add "-1" to range of (b) , i think it has to do how elements in a list are counted right?